# How to create view using STR_TO_DATE in mysql.?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have a table with 5 columns, created from csv file.
I was unable to load it using str_to_date function on date column.
I also need to create a view to use it in php scripts, So now I would like to create a view where i could change the createdate column from varchar to date format.
Would anyone please tell me the correct synatx.?

```
table_name: mytable
id varchar, 
createdate varchar, 
docid varchar, 
docsize number, 
dept varchar.
```

P.S. :- No. of column could go upto 5000 in a month.

Comment: Instead of naming all columns, do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`mytable\`;` and paste the output.

Comment: `id` is varchar? Please, redesign your table.

Comment: id is empid which is combination of alphabet and no. So i dont hav a choice other than varchar.
I want to create a view to convert date element to date format, is it possible.?

Comment: Thank you all. I have solved this.

create view mdview
as
Select col1, str_to_date(col2,'%d/%m/%Y'), col3, col4, col5 
from tbl_name;

Answer (score 0):

Using **CONVERT()** function in mysql you can convert any datatype to another..

Click for more details about [**CONVERT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///cast-functions.html#function_convert)